# Java Remote Class Loading secure?

Tags: java, security, classloader, urlclassloader

I know that jar files (or class files) can be loaded remotely with URLClassLoader. But does this method provide any protection against piracy?

So lets say i have a jar file on the server, and on the client side, i can dynamically load the jar with URLClassLoader. But what about security? Is the jar file downloaded to a temp directory on the client? Can somebody have access to the contents of the jar file and decompile it?

Thanks in advance,

Onur

Answer (score 2):

Yes AND no:

- Yes, this is safe as the loaded classes won't have more permissions than your own code.
- No, as you don't control it. So these classes may do anything allowed by the permissions of your code, even things you didn't expect.

For example, should your code be a Java applet executed in a browser, the loaded classes won't be able to download stuff from a random URL (`SecurityException`). But they might display things you didn't expect.